# 2.8 Bone editing and pose problems, cant select single bones

Tags: bones, edit-mode, weight-painting, pose-mode

I´ve built a rig in 2.8, however when I try to select a single bone in edit or pose mode, i can´t.
All i can do, is doubleclick the first bone i created to cycle through the other bones. I have tried in new files and rightclicking, but  the problem persists.
Help, i need to get an animation done soon and this is breaking my back.

Comment: Did you try adding bones in a new scene to see if there is a problem with your settings? Also try loading factory defaults and test. I can't seem to replicate your issue.

Comment: I used default factory settings and created a new scene, the problem persists
i download 2.8 again, maybe thatll help

Comment: Did you create a new simple scene with a few bones and the default cube to verify that selection works as it should? Or did you open your file with the selection issue?

Comment: I did that, the issue however persisted. In the end Im guessing my machine is to old. So i did my project on a friends PC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem. I just went into Animation mode and deleted my mesh to grab a bone in pose mode. That's not a full solution, but at least it gives some control to explore the problem further.